# how to send emails in multiple languages with Rails Actionmailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I have my site in two languages (English and Spanish). I have form when the user submit it it sends an an HTML e-mail(in English) to his e-mail account.

How can configure my actionmailer so it can send the user the e-mail in the right language?

I've created the views

```
confirmation_email.es.html.erb
confirmation_email.en.html.erb
```

Where do I specify which template to use?

Answer (score 2):

this should be automatically handled by rails template resolution.

try the following to send in spanish:

```
  I18n.with_locale :es do
    UserMailer.confirmation_email(user).deliver!
  end
```

Comment: Thank you @phoet, I want to send the email depending on the language the user is at. How it should be that condition?

Comment: that depends on where you store "the language the user is at"